# Storing large data on the server

Tags: django

I am using Django to write a website that conducts a user study. For each user, I need to load a large amount of data in RAM, and let that data be accessible throughout this particular user's time on the website. When the user leaves the website, this data can be discarded. When the next user visits the website, a new set of data will be loaded into RAM. The data is the same size, but of different value, for each user. A maximum of four users will be visiting the website at any one time. The data can be up to 100MB in size.

What is the best way to implement this? The only solution I can think of is to store the data as a session variable, but I'm wondering whether this involves any memory copying, which might be slow given that the data is large?

Comment: What makes you think you need to store this data in RAM? And if you do, will that be server-side or client-side? What will you need so much data for? How many distinct users will you need to store this for? So many questions, so few answers!

Comment: I need it to be in RAM because I am doing some machine learning calculations based on the user's input, so it must be server-side. Only 4 users at a time will need this data in RAM. If I don't store it in RAM, then it will slow down my system too much if I need to keep loading it from the server's hard drive.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't allocate RAM via Django. If you have heavy processes to run, run them asynchronously - you probably need Celery: 
https://pypi.python.org/pypi/django-celery
http://www.celeryproject.org/

First do your "machine learning calculations based on the user's input" in a Django command. Then you can check with Celery when to run it...

The workflow would be:
- user enters some data in a form
- user submits it: that saves a record in the database
- the command is automatically ran afterwards using that record